# Отображение двух прямоугольников на QGraphicsScene()

Tags: c++, qt

Есть сцена размером 1700 пикселей scene = new QGraphicsScene();
У неё ограничена область видимости размером scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,480);
На этой сцене есть объект player.

Мне надо отобразить два прямоугольника(справа и слева) на сцене. При нажатии они будут перемещать объект player по сцене на определенное количество пикселей.

У меня сейчас в голове крутиться два решения.

1. Сделать два прямоугольника QGraphicsRectItem и поместить их на сцену, и каждый раз рез их перемещать на количество пикселей, на которые сместился player.
2. Создать новую сцену, например controlScene = new QGraphicsScene() с фиксированным разрешением 800 на 480 и туда поместить кнопки управления и связать с player. Такое возможно?

Теперь вопросы.

1. Можно ли как-то отобразить прямоугольники и привязать их к видимой области сцены (800,480), чтобы каждый раз не перемещать их?
2. Если делать моим первым способом, то это сильно скажется на производительности? Просто на моей сцене есть другие динамические объекты.
3. Какой вариант предпочтительнее?